# Execution tree in .NET

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I am running an old C++ application of about 250K lines of code & have made many changes to it. When I execute it, the first output will be a screen that gets loaded. But to load the screen, I have to traverse about 'x' functions across 'y' cpp files.

Is there any automated/semi-automated manner I can get this execution tree in .NET ? I am using Visual Studio 2019.

When I execute, I get some errors which I am fixing (this is not the problem). I want to know what is the function & file tree my code needs to traverse before that first screen gets loaded.

I can correct each error when I get it & I will eventually load the first output, but I need to know how long this piece of rope is.

Comment: Put a break point and take a look at the stack trace. Note that optimizer can change it significantly.

Comment: look at the stack trace after it stops at the break point. Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Hi Usha, any update of this issue? Does the call stack window or parallel stacks window work for you?  :)

Answer (score 0):

As Evg and phuclv mentioned, you can use stack trace feature to get the execution tree.

For example, with the below demo C++ console app:

```
#include <iostream>

int MyTest3(int c) {
    std::cout << "This is MyTest3";
    return c;
}
int MyTest2(int b) {
    MyTest3(b);
    return b;
}
int MyTest(int a) {
    MyTest2(a);
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    MyTest(1);
}
```

You can add the breakpoint like this:

[image]

After that, press F5 or click debug button, and then the open call stack window or parallel stacks windows, both of them can show the execution tree:

[image]

[image]

You can found those two windows in this place(Debug->Windows->Parallel Stacks or Debug->Windows->Call Stack):

[image]

Please notice those two windows need to open after the debug start.

You can refer to these official documents:

[How to use call stack window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2022)

[Parallel Stack Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-parallel-stacks-window?view=vs-2022)